# Who to use bot framework language translation feature

Tags: botframework

I already created a functionnal bot using Bot Framework.

Now i'm trying to use language translation feature, but i can't find how to achieve this.
I enabled the "Translate channel messages" option but the messages are always received with language set to "en" even if message content is not english.

Any pointer would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: see http://docs.botframework.com/connector/bot-options/#translation-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user you can change the language by writing "I want to talk in [supported language]". Or just write the name of the language and the bot framework should be clever enough to recognize what you want.

On back end side you receive the translated text but you also have access to the original text and the original language.

Comment: It works! Also, i send bot responses in "en" language, but they are not translated to user language, is it possible? Thank you

Comment: I tried it with the basic sample from the C# template and it works. In the sample the response message gets created this way: `message.CreateReplyMessage($"You sent {length} characters");`. I've tried it with "en" language parameter too and it still works. The language stuff doesn't work in the emulator, but I guess you know that.

Answer (score 1):

In v4.0, you can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");` to translate your existing language to the language you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft closed "Translate channel messages" this feature from v3.0 of Microsoft Bot Framework update.